# Ubuntu 14.04 live cd while booting asks for username and password (Installing in Virtual Box)

Tags: 14.04, password, username

Guys i am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 in my virtual box, but it repeatedly asks for username and password. Not able to solve this problem, None of my ubuntu .iso asked this before installation.. pls help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last i solved the real problem i got, i placed the downloaded .iso in my torrent folder and started the bitorrent using this link-> "http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads".

->It was at 99.9%, remaining 0.1% got completed and now its works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

**Update** (after comments):
It's always a good rule to check if the download was finished in the proper way.
The iso images are released with a checksum code for this purpose available from the same page of the downloads [In this case from here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/).

> Those are the MD5SUM for the relative files
>
> dccff28314d9ae4ed262cfc6f35e5153 *ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso
> c4d4d037d7d0a05e8f526d18aa25fb5e *ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso
> 01545fa976c8367b4f0d59169ac4866c *ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso
> 08d25bf879e353686a974b7b14ae7d81 *ubuntu-14.04-server-i386.iso
> b31731ea6cdbebe1d02f8193db420886 *wubi.exe

---

If you downloaded a ready to use [ubuntu image for virtualbox](http://virtualboxes.org/images/ubuntu/) usually the passwords are

```
Active user account(s) (username/password): ubuntu/reverse
```

If you downloaded from another source you should refer to the download page.
Note that you can always install in virtualbox a ready image and after upgrade it

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

In the past there was some livecd for which the username was `ubuntu` (or `lubuntu`...) with no password.

Comment: No, its an Ubuntu Desktop version .iso 32 bit. (ubuntu/reverse)->no success, Sudo apt...->No access to terminal..    Downloaded link:http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso

Comment: It depends from who prepared the iso (aka from where you downloaded). Seldom it asks for a username and password to begin to install (it will be the 1st user you can use to login). Did you refer to this moment?

Comment: I don't find any such information regarding username and passoword in the ubuntu.com. I have added few screen shots pls check:-> https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7U7tF2SDKJdS0I1SkpnQUxQSWs&usp=sharing

Comment: It gives you 2 times a _corruption_ error. Try for 1st to verify you have a NOT corrupted iso. Do the MD5SUM (or another) and make a comparison with the one you find [on the same page](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/MD5SUMS). If you have no problem to do a new download you can take a pre-made image for virtualbox and after upgrade from *inside* the virtual machine.

Comment: Okay i got the solution for my problem, i checked the MD5SUM->not matched. Hence, i downloaded the "utopic-desktop-i386" of ubuntu 14.04 from "http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/utopic-desktop-i386.iso" and its working like a charm. I truly appreciate the time you spent to help me.